# Simple Twitter API not working in PHP

Tags: php, twitter, api

I've been following the instructions in http://www.tech-faq.com/send-tweets-to-your-twitter-account-via-php.html to post in my Twitter account from a PHP script.

Basically, I have two API files (OAuth.php and twitteroauth.php) and an index.php file to post.

However, it is not working. Whenever I load index.php I have to wait for a while, but finally I get an empty page (as expected) but nothing is published in twitter.

So far I have tried:

- Creating a new Twitter App.
- Made sure that the App has the permission to write.
- Resetting the access tokens.
  Using exactly the code provided in that page, without adding anything by my own.

Some time ago, when Twitter was using API 1, I could post in twitter with my web server. Now I was creating a new script, and Twitter is using API 1.1. I'm afraid that maybe it has something to do with https or SSL, but I don't know about this. I'm using a shared paid hosting.

Thanks!

Comment: twitter API1.1 do not require SSL check this http://www.walkswithme.net/latest-tweets-joomla-module its used with API1.1 its joomla module to display your tweets in your website, I think you can achieve your requirement with proper code to post on twitter

Comment: I took the OAuth.php and twitteroauth.php files from that module and the same problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?PHP
require_once 'twitteroauth.php';

define("CONSUMER_KEY", "Aof0w....");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "qtAHOMgeS...");
define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "731432660-X9kaxI91...");
define("OAUTH_SECRET", "66I6YjxsL1bDw4...");

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');

$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'test'));

?>
```

After requesting Read & Write permissions, you have to RECREATE your access tokens to reflect the new permissions. Once I popped in the new access tokens, everything worked fine.

A working example for [Post to twitter using PHP Oauth API](http://www.walkswithme.net/post-to-twitter-using-php-oauth-api)

Hope it helps..

Comment: The link you posted to walkswithme.net caused my Avast! Anti-Virus to block... `http://sa.entireweb.com/sasense?nc` / `JS:Redirector-BEE [Trj]`

Comment: its strange! you cannot browse any page from the link ? its live an no issue with spam or virus

Comment: @w3d In any case you can't browse the page then direct download from this link http://www.walkswithme.net/?wpdmact=process&did=MTcuaG90bGluaw==

Comment: Any page on your blog triggers my anti virus... it appears to be complaining about the advert/network that is being served (in an iframe) - this is blocked. This appears to result in a malicious redirect (so it thinks).

Comment: @w3d thanks for your detailed checking, even that ads have no usage i will remove that today, thanks..

Comment: I downloaded the working example but the problem remains the same. I only changed twitter.php to use my access tokens with write permission. But when I execute it I have to wait for a while and finally I get an empty page (as expected) but nothing is published in twitter.

Comment: make sure your app on twitter have proper privilege  to write own twitter, Once you change the access permission token may change that you have to correct on the API file. It will work , I already attached an image from twitter account. Or you can see that on my twitter account